# SQL Query between time stamps

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM abc 
WHERE filehash IN (
  SELECT xyz 
  FROM 123 
  WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timecreated,'%m-%d-%Y') >= "01-01-2000")
```

But I need a time range: >= "01-01-2000" AND <= "01-02-2000"

I tried e few things, but nothing worked.
Any help for a query is appreciated.

Comment: You can use [`BETWEEN`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/between-and/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting the unix timestamp to string for comparison, convert the two input strings to unix timestamp and compare:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM abc
WHERE filehash IN (
   SELECT xyz
   FROM 123
   WHERE timecreated >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01')
   AND   timecreated <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2000-01-02')
)
```

See [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) documentation for details about how the string should be formatted.